# how to make an laravel 8 API for saving an array of objects

Tags: reactjs, laravel-8

{owner: '456123', holders: Array(2)}

holders:

```
0: { equipments: 'test', release_by: 'test'}

1: {equipments: 'test', release_by: 'test'}
```

owner: "456123"
}

i have this kind of array values object from my react formik app and i want to save it into the laravel backend database anybody tell me how to do this one using laravel 8 thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your json object like this format -

```json
{
    owner:456123,
    holders: [
        { 
            equipments: 'test', 
            release_by: 'test'
        },
        { 
            equipments: 'test', 
            release_by: 'test'
        }
    ]
}
```

This process you can follow.

1. Create a `holder` model. This `holder` model have relation with `owner` model.
2. After creating the relationship, you need to create a controller for consume the request. This controller must have a [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation) for validating your inputs.
3. In this controller, you can insert your data using `batch` operation. [How to bulk insert in laravel](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/batch-insert-in-laravel-52)

I think it will help you for farther working process.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have the table and have only columns named equipments and release_by other than id (which must be autogenerated) ,created_at and updated_at you can use
`table::insert($array)` if you have other columns and they are nullable or you have to insert some other values you can use

```
$newData = new Table;
foreach ($array as $data) {
 $newData = new Table;
 $newData->equipments  => data['equipments'];
 $newData->release_by    => data['release_by'];
 $newData->save();
}
```

Comment: oh i forgot im using laravel 8 sanctum is that the same?

Comment: yes it doesnt matters